# Make a job run last in a pipeline on Zuul

Tags: zuul-ci

I want a job to be ran last in a pipeline like this one *check*:

```
    - project:
        merge-mode: squash-merge 

        check:
          jobs:
            - job1
            - job2
            - job3
```

So the job3 will only run when job1 and job2 have finished. Using **dependencies** is not a alternative because it will only run if the job1 and job2 don't fail.
Tried using jobs.requires and job.provides like so but it didn't work either:

```
check:
  jobs:
    - job1:
        provides: testing
    - job2
        provides: testing
    - job3
        requires: testing
```

Any suggestions?